# Spring-test and ServletContextListener in web.xml

Tags: integration, web.xml, spring-test

i try to use spring-test(3.2.10) and integration tests with TestNG by this [link](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html).

I created RootTest.java

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/test/resources/root-context2.xml")
public class ReferenceServiceTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {
...
```

spring context loaded success. But my global variables not instantiated because web.xml ignored. In web.xml i have my own "listener-class"(implementation of ServletContextListener) and "context-param". How i can load web.xml context(and calls all application startup listeners) with spring integration test context?

Answer (score 6):

As stated in the reference manual, the Spring MVC Test Framework...

> "loads the actual Spring configuration through the TestContext
>   framework and always uses the DispatcherServlet to process requests
>   thus approximating full integration tests without requiring a running
>   Servlet container."

The key point there is "without ... a Servlet container". Thus `web.xml` does not come into the picture here. In other words, there is no way for configuration in `web.xml` to have an affect on integration tests using the Spring MVC Test Framework.

Now, having said that, it is possible to register a Servlet `Filter` with `MockMvc` like this:

```
mockMvcBuilder.addFilters(myServletFilter);
```

or

```
mockMvcBuilder.addFilters(myResourceFilter, "/resources/*");
```

And you can configure `context-param` entries by adding them manually to the `ServletContext` (which is actually Spring's `MockServletContext`) before you execute assertions on `MockMvc` like this:

```
wac.getServletContext().setInitParameter(name, value);
```

But... there is no way to configure a `ServletContextListener` using Spring MVC Test. If you want to have a *listener* applied to all of your requests that pass through Spring MVC, as an alternative you could consider implementing a custom `HandlerInterceptor` or `WebRequestInterceptor` (see [Configuring interceptors](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-config-interceptors) in the reference manual).

Regards,

Sam

Comment: The call `wac.getServletContext()` will return javax.servlet.ServletContext. 

You will have to cast this: 

`((MockServletContext)wac.getServletContext()).setInitParameter(name, value)`

Answer (score 0):

Try with a MockServletContext

```
@Before
public void before() {
    MockServletContext mockServletContext = new MockServletContext();
    mockServletContext.setInitParameter("parameterName", "parameterValue");
    new MyListenerClass().contextInitialized(new ServletContextEvent(mockServletContext));
}
```